# PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)Serial port COM4

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I'm very new to using ESP8266,I tried to upload this simple script

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(D4, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(D4, LOW);
  delay(1000);

}
```

to the node mcu(ESP8266) but I keep on getting this error `esptool.py v3.0 A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)Serial port COM4`

Anyone answering the question ,explain it step by step and do remember that I've zero knowledge on esp8266.
I've tried installing driver's but still the same error.

Comment: Facing the same problem T_T

Comment: I found the solution…before you flash on flash .bin file you have to click flash button on the nodemcu or if you get the same error,install nodemcu drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click flash botton on nodemcu before flashing the file or update the driver’s

Comment: This did not do anything for me.

Answer (score 6):

As many said here: uninstall the driver and install it again. [This is how-to](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all). Sparkfun has link to download uninfected driver which works.

Comment: I can confirm rolling back to this version solved the issue for me.
I was initially using the latest driver from wch's website.

Answer (score 0):

Permission errors are usually caused by the driver CH34x is not working in your computer. Try update the driver or reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Try to rollback the driver to its original version and restart your computer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I rolled back my driver for the ch34x and voila... all working! hint: you may find some boards will program successfully and others not. In my case I found that only the ch340 boards failed. All others passed with flying colors.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens on windows 11. Uninstall your driver and restart your PC or laptop then install the driver back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft recommended driver block rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZROi.png)

If you are struggling w/ this problem on win11 try doing this then reinstall the esp drivers.
Turn off that function on: Icon Tray>Device Security>core isolation details>Microsoft recommended driver block rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had uploaded a sketch earlier without any problem. But this time I got this Permission Error(13, ...

I was sure it was not a driver problem. I was just using it for other devices a fwe minutes ago.

The difference was:

The NodeMCU board was connected to other devices on the breadboard.

I unplugged them all. Everything worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

I had the ESP32 plugged into a USB hub. Changed it to a USB in PC and it worked.